# Wrap expanded container

Tags: css

I have an expandable container in CSS.  When collapsed it looks like.(below)

- first
- second
- third

If I expand the first item this happens(below)

- first +second
      +third

The float left looks like it causing the problem, but without it formatting is off.  How can I make everything else wrap after expanded.

```
div.wrapper{
    float:left;
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Comment: `display: block` or `display: inline-block`
You could also add a fiddle, would make that easier..

Comment: Can you show us more context? (html/css?)

Answer (score 0):

```
div.wrapper{
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to 'clear' your flow.

```
.wrapper {
    float:left;
    clear:both;
    position:relative;
    margin: 30px 30px 30px 30px;
}
```

No need to change the display property nor make it behave like something else than a 'block'.

[Fiddled here](http://jsfiddle.net/QP3CV/) where i added a border just for visual.

Answer (score 0):

Just aftyer the closing div tag of .wrapper, put in a clear both div:

```
// html code
// wrapper contents
</div>
<div style="clear: both"></div>
```